# how to write a power-shell script to build a angular project

Tags: angular, powershell

I am trying to write a power-shell script to achieve the following steps,

1. Build the angular project placed in a particular folder location.
2. After building, convert it to a bundle
3. Once the package file is created, place the package in a server.

   ```
   Task Build -Depends CreatePackage {
      Initiate-Build
     }

   Task CreatePackage -Depends Init {
     Exec {npm run build --prod $FilePath}
    }
   ```

   I am not able to think through, how to start and proceed. Can anyone share me an example or correct me on how to implement this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be publishing to a server using a NuGet package? That seems odd to me because NuGet packages are used to add dependencies to development projects, not to deploy (and configure) built web-applications.

Comment: Can't you use the AngularCli for this?

Comment: @Onera in azure pipelines you can build angular project you dont have to save as nuget package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to solve the build and release problem using build pipeline then this could be done with built-in [npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) plugins as well which is quite good and do not require much efforts to integrate/add.

Here are the steps and link you can follow to implement the same:

1. You can add the [npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task for building angular project and
   configure accordingly.
2. Then add [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task in the build pipeline to copy dist folder for the 
   release artefacts.

See the tasks you would use to achieve the same.

[image]

Comment: I created the above tasks, but since dist folder wont be present in, how can we copy files while speicifying it in the src and dest paths?

Comment: That dist folder will not be visible because that only creates after npm build ran successfully in the agent system but the path you are seeing is referring to the source control. You just need to provide the path of the dust folder. ie $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Your project path/dist